# Using this jQuery script for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I am totally new to jQuery and just tinkering at the moment, I am using a test script at the moment (below) what I want to achieve is to have images where when its clicked a div slides down with more info - similar to the new google images effect.

The problem with the script below is that it loads with the div open (I need it to open on click) and also, this will only work on one div, do I need to do the script multiple times for multiple divs?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#clickme').click(function() {
          $('#me').animate({
               height: 'toggle'
               }, 500
          );
     });
});
</script>


<div id="clickme" style="background-color: #333333; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px; width: 200px; cursor:pointer;">
  Click here to toggle me in and out =)
</div>
<img id="me" src="http://www.randomsnippets.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/2.png" alt="It&#039;s me....ah!!!" title="Allen Liu" width="100" height="77" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-552" style="border: none;" />
```

Comment: have you considered assigning the function to a class and then assigning the class to a div?

Comment: Use a class: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use the same ID for multiple elements. Instead, use a class. jQuery will only select the first occurrence of an ID and will ignore the rest.

Secondly, you will need to provide the function some context - i.e., `$(this).next()`- This is because when you have multiple elements with the `clickme` class, the browser will know that it will have to select the ***next*** occurring element with a class of `me`, instead of any other `.me` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide image onload
    $('.me').hide();

    // Provide context for each click event
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
         $(this).next('.me').animate({
              height: 'toggle'
              }, 500
         );
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clickme" style="background-color: #333333; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px; width: 200px; cursor:pointer;">
  Click here to toggle me in and out =)
</div>
<img class="me" src="http://www.randomsnippets.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/2.png" alt="It&#039;s me....ah!!!" title="Allen Liu" width="100" height="77" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-552" style="border: none;" />
```

Comment: That still won't address his second issue, which is that the image is visible when the document loads.

Comment: It will address /part/ of his issue though. Revising my answer as we speak.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :-) it's all pretty easy stuff really I guess, we all start from somewhere! thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To start off with the div hidden, you can set it to `display: none`, either using inline styles or (preferably) a `<style>` element or CSS file.

Then you can uses classes and relative positioning to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('img.clickable').click(function() {
          $(this).prev('.image-info').first().animate({
               height: 'toggle'
               }, 500
          );
     });
});
</script>


<div style="background-color: #333333; color: #FFFFFF; 
      padding: 10px; width: 200px; cursor:pointer; display:none;" 
      class="image-info">
  Info about the image you clicked
</div>
<img src="http://www.randomsnippets.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/2.png" 
     alt="It&#039;s me....ah!!!" title="Allen Liu" width="100" height="77" 
   class="alignnone size-full wp-image-552 clickable" style="border: none;" />
```

Comment: I personally refrain from using CSS to hide elements that are revealed by JS thereafter, considering that some (although a fractionally small percentage) of users have JS disabled on their browsers. If that is the case, the element will not be displayed when the user loads the page.

Comment: That's a good point. Hadn't thought of using JS to hide stuff when the page loads instead of using CSS, but I can see the value in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the above commenter suggested, and change your image to a class based approach.

Secondly, add this to the beginning of your `document.ready` block

```
$('.me').hide();
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cBgMZ/1/)

Comment: @Dom Yeah, I sure did.  How does this not answer that?

Comment: "this will only work on one div, do I need to do the script multiple times for multiple divs?"

You will need to provide the context upon the firing of each `.click()` event.

Comment: Which is presented in the fiddle.  You're right, I made the mistake of glossing over that first question and went straight for the second.  I updated my answer to point to a commenter with the appropriate response for the first.  Thank you.